# Cambiar keys de un objeto

Tags: javascript, web

Tengo un objeto que recibo de la siguiente forma:

```
[{"pickingID": 2112,
"pickingCode": 987,
"articleBarCode": "7797039002206",
"articleQuantity": 2,
"articlePending": 2,
"articleStatus": "1"}]
```

Y yo lo necesito con la siguiente estructura:

```
{"7797039002206": {
"quantity": 2}}
```

Como pueden ver la key del objeto es el "articleBarCode" y el valor es la cantidad, pero con la key con otro nombre: "quantity"

Como puedo transformar mi array de objeto que recibo a un objeto con el articleBarCode como key el articleQuantity como valor pero con el nombre de quantity?

Yo lo intenté de la siguiente forma

```
   const pickingFormated = pickingDetail.reduce((acc, el) => ({
        quantity: el.articleQuantity, 
        [el.articleBarCode]: el,
    }),[])
```

Pero no me lo transforma de la forma que necesito con el articleBarCode como key y quantity como valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma

```
var objeto = [{"pickingID": 2112,
"pickingCode": 987,
"articleBarCode": "7797039002206",
"articleQuantity": 2,
"articlePending": 2,
"articleStatus": "1"}]

var nuevoObjeto = {};
nuevoObjeto[objeto[0].articleBarCode] = {'quantity': objeto[0].articleQuantity};

console.log(nuevoObjeto);
```

Explicación:

Primero creas un objeto vacío `var nuevoObjeto = {};`

Para asignar una llave con el valor de una variable puedes utilizar corchetes `[]` de esta forma `nuevoObjeto[objeto[0].articleBarCode]`

Luego esa llave se convierte en un nuevo objeto

```
nuevoObjeto[objeto[0].articleBarCode] = {'quantity': objeto[0].articleQuantity};
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacerlo con la funcion map

```js
const pickingDetail = [{"pickingID": 2112,
    "pickingCode": 987,
    "articleBarCode": "7797039002206",
    "articleQuantity": 2,
    "articlePending": 2,
    "articleStatus": "1"}];

const pickingFormated = pickingDetail.map(item => {
  const obj = {};
  obj[item.articleBarCode] = {
  'quantity': item.articleQuantity
  }
  return obj;
});

console.log(pickingFormated);
```

por cada objeto dentro del arreglo pickingDetail te va a generar un objeto con el formato deseado

Answer (score -1):

Gracias por sus respuestas, lo terminé resolviendo antes de que me respondieran. Lo hice de la siguiente forma:

```
   const nuevoObjeto = objeto.reduce((acc, el) => ({
    [el.articleBarCode]: {quantity:el.articleQuantity}
}),{})
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).